# file_put_contents returning null on using json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to place the json_encoded variable on to a file using file_put_contents. I do not know why its returning a null value on the destination file.

```
$json1=json_encode($php);
file_put_contents("path/text.txt",$json1);
```

Comment: Add your code in your question, If you really need help

Comment: If you want to store your json data into file, it is not `file_get_contents` but `file_put_contents`

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around? `file_get_contents()` loads the contents into a string...

Comment: sorry my bad i mistyped because of tension

Comment: You should debug first before posting a question, have you tried echoing `$json1`.

Comment: (1) what is the contents of `$php`? (maybe show us the output of  `print_r($php)`). (2) what does `$json1` contain after `json_encode()`? -- ie maybe it's `json_encode()` that's the problem, not `file_put_contents()`. (3) Maybe `file_put_contents()` is failing: Have you checked the return value?

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` will set a `null` value in elements that contain an invalid (non-UTF-8) character.

Make sure your incoming data doesn't contain invalid characters. If it's coming from a different encoding, use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv) to convert it to UTF-8 first.

Comment: how exactly? should i use iconv()

Comment: @user2129868: see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: so i should change the utf-8 character

Comment: so how should i use it? use it to convert utf-8 first?